What is the representation postulated by representationalists who don't accept sense-data?
On the PhilPapers survey representationalism and sense-datum theory are separate options. I have also elsewhere on the internet seen talk of a modern representationalism which is sometimes characterised as direct realist, and definitely does not postulate the existence of sense-data. What I can't quite get is what the form of this representation of the external world is if it's not sense-data. I haven't seen answers which don't themselves just refer to another 'representation' of something. Can anyone help?

Sense-data were seen as entirely non-conceptual, mental "copies" of outside objects. Current theories take perceptual representations to have conceptual aspects in one way or another. In intentionalism, they are close to objects or propositions, i.e. have have semantic values, in adverbialism, they are close to propositional attitudes, see SEP. The idea that the "immediate given" is, in fact, conceptually mediated goes back to Hegel and was promoted in analytic philosophy by Sellars.
